# GMS send SMS text messages many times

Tags: softwareserial, gsm

The GSM sends many SMS text messages and does not stop. How to send only one SMS?
This is my code:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(9, 10);
char msg;
int vibr_pin = 7;

void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(9600);   // Setting the baud rate of GSM Module  
  Serial.begin(9600);   // Setting the baud rate of Serial Monitor (Arduino)
  pinMode(vibr_pin, INPUT);
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {
  int a;
  a = digitalRead(vibr_pin);
  if (a == 0) {
    mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
    delay(1000);  // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second
    mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+60125456758\"\r"); // Replace x with mobile number
    delay(1000);
    mySerial.println("test 1,2,3"); // The SMS text you want to send
    delay(100);
    mySerial.println((char) 26); // ASCII code of CTRL+Z
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
After I change `if (a==0)` to `if(a!=0)`, it only sends message when the vibration sensor is moving. How to send sms when sensor is not moving?

Comment: my vibration sensor sw-420

Comment: use a `flag` variable to `remember` if you sent a message

Answer (score 0):

```
int a;
a = digitalRead(vibr_pin);
if (a == 0) {
```

This sends an SMS text message every time a is 0. I'm not sure what vibr_pin does, but maybe you want to check only for a trigger (from `a != 0` to `a == 0`).

In that case, use a boolean to check if the SMS text message has been sent, and reset the boolean when a goes from `!=0` to `0`.

Comment: after i change if (a==0) to if(a!=0) it only send massage when the vibration sensor is moving. how to send sms when sensor not moving

Comment: Use a boolean (check when the sensor transitions from not moving to moving or vice versa). When that boolean is set (or reset) send the SMS and change the boolean.